# Variable Replacement in sed

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, ssh, sed

Does anyone know why this script wouldn't work?

filename: db

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Must specify source DB environment"
    echo "One of s (for Staging), p (for Production)"
    exit
elif [ "$1" == "s" -o "$1" == "p" ]; then
    if [ "$1" == "s" ]; then
        echo "Connecting to Staging DB"
        URL='staging\.example\.com'
        PATH='/var/www/vhosts/staging\.example\.com'
    else
        echo "Connecting to Production DB"
        URL='example\.com'
        PATH='/var/www/vhosts/example\.com'
    fi
    ssh host "mysqldump -udbuser -pdbpass staging | gzip -9" | gzip -d | sed -e "s+$URL+example\.local+g" -e "s+$PATH+/Library/WebServer/Documents/example+g" | mysql -uroot -proot example_local
fi
```

I get the following errors:

```
./db: line 14: ssh: command not found
./db: line 14: gzip: command not found
./db: line 14: sed: command not found
./db: line 14: mysql: command not found
```

Notes:

- Permissions on `./db` are 777.
- `host` is saved in `.ssh/config`. I can run `ssh host` and get into the remote machine no prob.
- the mysql credentials are correct for both remote and local
- I can run that final ssh one-liner on the command line just fine. I'm pretty sure it's the variable replacement in sed that's messing things up.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I'm running as my... I don't know what you call it... "home" user on OSX. @anubhava had it right that I was overwriting my system $PATH with the server path in use for the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is lines like this in your script:

```
PATH='/var/www/vhosts/staging\.example\.com'
```

Where you're setting reserved path `env variable PATH` to something else and that removes `/bin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin` etc from `PATH` which is needed to run core unix binaries like `sed, awk, grep, find` etc.

It is better to use a different variable name other than `PATH` like:

```
MYPATH='/var/www/vhosts/staging\.example\.com'
```

Comment: Of course! duh. Thanks! SO won't let me accept for another few minutes.